# Facebook recommend button showing wrong image

Tags: image, facebook, facebook-like

I have already searched the site but I can't find an answer to this. My problem is that Facebook is showing the wrong image after I press the 'recommend' button (it's the same as the 'Like' button but with different text).

The webpage is here: http://www.bamarang.in/perfume-tree/ and the facebook debugger is here: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bamarang.in%2Fperfume-tree%2F%3Ffb%3Dfgfgfg

The website needs an email but you can use a fake one to enter, as there is no confirmation.

As you can see everything seems to be correct but the wrong image is displayed. I've tried clearing the cache, on both the browser and Facebook (this last one by writing the webpage url's in the developer tool) but to no avail.

You can also see the webpage's source to check that all the OG tags are there and correct.

What else can I be missing? Please help.

See the wrong image showing up here: [www.crosstastemovies.com/temp/fb_error1.jpg](http://www.crosstastemovies.com/temp/fb_error1.jpg)
See the FB **scraper** showing the correct image here: [www.crosstastemovies.com/temp/fb_error2.jpg](http://www.crosstastemovies.com/temp/fb_error2.jpg)

I've updated the question to add the screen shots.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what's going wrong here but you need to provide a description or screenshot of what you expect to see and what you are actually seeing - as far as I can see the page is linting and being scraped by the Like/Recommend button correctly, the only issue being that you haven't specified fb:admins and/or fb:app_id tags

Comment: Hi. I've added screen shots but stackoverflow won't let me show them or link them because of the spam filter, so please see the urls' above. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided for your site is: `http://www.bamarang.in/perfume-tree/` but the link with the debugger is: `http://www.bamarang.in/perfume-tree/?fb=fgfgfg`.
As you can see those two urls are not the same.

I curled both urls, the first one returns a redirect to `https://www.bamarang.in/customer/account/create/` and when curling that the output has no og tags in it (check yourself in the [debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=https://www.bamarang.in/customer/account/create/)).

The 2nd url (with the ?fb=...) indeed has the og tags.
What's the url you're using with the recommend button?

You should probably just output the og tags even when the `fb` parameter is not present, don't forget that people can just copy/paste the url into their status on fb, you have no control over how people share.

Comment: Hi. The tags are dynamic, they are always there. I have to put "?fb=something" to bypass the login page. The url is also dynamic so it is correct, you can check it at the facebook debugger tool.

Comment: The tags are not always there, as I showed you in my example. What url are using for the plugin? (the `data-href` or similar)

Comment: The facebook button is called like this: <div class="fb-like" data-href="' . $url . '" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="100" data-show-faces="false" data-action="recommend"></div> . The url is dynamic. Whatever the current url is will be pasted there. The initial page (login) has no facebook buttons, so that's why you can't see any.

Comment: I see. I get the same image at facebook as the one shown in the debugger, and the screenshots urls don't work anymore so I don't have a reference.

Comment: You get the same image? If that is so then maybe this could be a cache problem. Could you please attach screenshots so I can show them to my boss? :)
By the way, my screenshots are back up.
Thanks